# pydantic basemodel "field" for validation purposes only

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

Consider the follwoing code illustrating use of the `pydantic` `BaseModel` with validation:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class User(BaseModel, frozen=True):
    id_key: int
    user_id: int

    @validator('user_id')
    def id_check(cls, v, values):
        if v > 2 * values['id_key'] + 1:
            raise ValueError('id check failed.')
        return v

user_dict = {'user_id': 10, 'id_key': 60}
u = User(**user_dict)
```

Now, in my application, I don't really want `id_key` to be a regular, accessible field in model instances like `u`--its sole purpose is for validating `user_id`.  For my example, is there a way to have access to `id_key` for validation purposes but not have it be a standard field?

Comment: What about using two classes? One with the `id_key` to perform the validation and another one without the `id_key` when you know that you have data that you can trust. The one with the `id_key` could inherit from the other one and just implement any additional validation you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `values` argument you have in your `id_check` function being the internal dict of attributes *already validated* for your instance, if you need to have `id_key` only at instantiation time for checking and not after that, you could simply remove it from `values`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class User(BaseModel, frozen=True):
    id_key: int
    user_id: int

    @validator('user_id')
    def id_check(cls, v, values):
        if v > 2 * values['id_key'] + 1:
            raise ValueError('id check failed.')
        values.pop('id_key')
        return v
```

```py
user_dict = {'user_id': 10, 'id_key': 60}
u = User(**user_dict)
print(u)
# output:
# user_id=10
```

There is one additional improvement I'd like to suggest for your code: in its present state, as pydantic runs the validations of all the fields before returning the validation errors, if you pass something completely invalid for `id_key` like "abc" for example, or omit it, it won't be added to `values`, and the validation of `user_id` will crash with `KeyError: 'id_key'`, swallowing all the rest of the validation process and returning no sensible message.

```py
user_dict = {'user_id': 10, 'id_key': 'abc'}
u = User(**user_dict)
# output:
# KeyError: 'id_key'
```

This is not very explicit, and might cause issues with your application if you expect a pydantic `ValidationError`. You might want to check that `id_key` is indeed present in `values` and raise the error cleanly if not.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class User(BaseModel, frozen=True):
    id_key: int
    user_id: int

    @validator('user_id')
    def id_check(cls, v, values):
        if 'id_key' not in values or v > 2 * values['id_key'] + 1:
            raise ValueError('id check failed.')
        values.pop('id_key')
        return v
```

```py
user_dict = {'user_id': 10, 'id_key': 'abc'}
u = User(**user_dict)
# output:
# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for User
# id_key
#   value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
# user_id
#   id check failed.(type=value_error)
```